# SocketIO "packet queue is empty, aborting” Error When Sending Message From Server

Tags: python, server, socket.io, client, python-socketio

I am having an issue with sending a SocketIO message from a WSGI server to a SocketIO client.  Messages going the other way (client to server) work fine without any issue.  The code is in Python using the `python-socketio` package and `eventlet` to create a WSGI server.  The server and the client run in different consoles on the same Windows machine.  Messages are sent by clicking a button.

Here is what happens:

1. In one console, the server is launched and a window with a button
   (that sends a message) appears.
2. In the other console, the client is launched.  A window with two
   buttons appears – one button initiates the connection to the server
   and the other button sends a message.
3. The client’s “Connect” button is clicked and the connection is made
   without issue.
4. The client’s “Send Msg” button is clicked and the sent data is
   printed in the server’s console (this works exactly as it should)
5. The server’s “Send Msg” button is clicked.  In the client console,
   nothing occurs for a while (I presume when the server polls again)
   and then the client’s disconnect() function executes (this is not
   what is expected)

The client console displays messages slightly differently depending on whether the client of the server sends the first message.

- If the server sends the first message, then when the client sends
  it’s message only the print statement from the disconnect() function
  is displayed.
- If the client sends the first message, then when the server sends it message, “packet queue
  is empty, aborting” is displayed followed by the print statement in
  the disconnect() function.

Why is the client not receiving the messages emitted from the server?

Here is complete server and client code that manifests the issue:

Server code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QDialog, QApplication
import socketio, sys, eventlet
from threading import Thread

class My_Class(QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(My_Class, self).__init__(parent)
    
    self.setWindowTitle("My SocketIO Server")
    self.resize(300,150)
    self.move(300, 200)
    
    self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
    self.btn1.setText('Send Msg')
    self.btn1.move(100,75)
    self.btn1.clicked.connect(send_message_to_client)
    
    self.show()    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='eventlet')

    def start_listening():
        eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), serverapp)
    
    @sio.event
    def connect(sid, environ):
        print('\nConnected with SID', sid)

    def send_message_to_client():
        print('\nSending from Button')
        sio.emit('Message_from_server', {"Message 1": "Hello"})

    @sio.event
    def message_from_client(sid, data):
        print('\nThis message came from the Client.', data, '\n')

    serverapp = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={'/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}})
    thread = Thread(target = start_listening, args=())
    thread.start()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = My_Class()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the client code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QDialog, QApplication
import socketio, sys

class My_Client(QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(My_Client, self).__init__(parent)
    
    self.setWindowTitle("My SocketIO Clent")
    self.resize(300,150)
    self.move(700, 200)
    
    self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
    self.btn1.setText('connect')
    self.btn1.move(50,75)
    self.btn1.clicked.connect(connect)

    self.btn2 = QPushButton(self)
    self.btn2.setText('Send Msg')
    self.btn2.move(175,75)
    self.btn2.clicked.connect(send_message_from_client)
    
    self.show()    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sio = socketio.Client()

    def connect():
        sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
        print('\nConnection established using SID', sio.sid)

    @sio.event
    def message_from_server(sid, data):
        print('\nMessage from server received with ', data)
    
    def send_message_from_client():
        print('\nMessage sent from Client')
        sio.emit('message_from_client', {'Message': 'Hello World'})

    @sio.event
    def disconnect():
        print('\nDisconnected from server\n')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = My_Client()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From pythong-socketio issues, it seems like you need to use `sio.wait`. It's mentioned in [#272](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio/issues/272) and [#922](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/922) of the python-socketio issues, and you can see them in `examples/client/ayncio` and `.../threads` example. It took a long time to fix this for me. I just hope this was mentioned in the documentation page.

Answer (score 4):

I was using the socketio.asyncServer and facing the same issue. The problem was the pingTimeout for my server was too small(5sec).
pingTimeout is the time in seconds that the client waits for the server to respond before disconnecting and by default it was set to 5sec. Increasing the  timeout interval to 60s, solved the issue for me.
In the server code, change

```
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='eventlet')
```

to the following

```
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='eventlet', ping_timeout=60)
```

OR

```
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(ping_timeout=60)
```

Answer (score 1):

So `packet queue is empty, aborting` is a product of the underlying python-engineio package and is triggered when empty payloads are sent and I believe when the ongoing PING / PONG between server and client is missed on the server-side.

As such, it looks like the main problem you're dealing with is the client is disconnecting because the server isn't able to PONG back to the client and the client eventually gives up and disconnects.

So the big question would be why the server can't get messages to the client (but can receive them). I would guess this has to do with threading somehow, either by running the eventlet server in a thread or maybe passing your `sio` functions to PyQt. I would suggest isolating the connection independent of PyQt operations and also trying the server either using `multiprocessing` or just running it flat out.

Comment: I tried your ideas.  (1) I removed PyQt and went with keyboard entry in the console to trigger the connection and emits.  Exact same results as when PyQt was used.  (2) I removed the threading (and kept PyQt out of the code).  The server took control of the console and I could not manually enter keyboard commands from the server side. (3) Exact switch from threading.Thread() to multiprocessing.Process().  The server did not start.  If all of the messages occur automatically (no input to trigger an emit or connection) messages go both directions without issue, but this does not solve my need.

Answer (score 1):

From pythong-socketio issues, it seems like you need to use `sio.wait`. It's mentioned in [#272](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio/issues/272) and [#922](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/922)

And you can see them in `examples/client` examples:

Asyncio (`examples/client/async`) ([link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/tree/main/examples/client/asyncio)) :

```
async def start_server():
    await sio.connect('http://localhost:5000', auth={'token': 'my-token'})
    await sio.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start_server())
```

Threads (`examples/client/threads`) ([link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/tree/main/examples/client/threads)):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('http://localhost:5000', auth={'token': 'my-token'})
    sio.wait()
```

So, in your case, it would be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    sio = socketio.Client()

    def connect():
        sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
        print('\nConnection established using SID', sio.sid)

        # === Add wait ===
        sio.wait()
```

I know this is question is long ago but I this was the only SO post that came up when I googled the error message.

It took a long time to fix this for me. I just hope this was mentioned in the documentation page.